# change windows time synchronization settings

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, time, service

How do I change the settings on a windows server 2008 box, so that the server synchronizes with time.windows.com more often?

Currently, it shows that the next synchronization time is 12 hrs from now. I want to synchronize more often, like once every couple of hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a single server, change
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\
TimeProviders\NtpClient\SpecialPollingInterval`
to the value (in seconds) that you want the interval to be.

For multiple servers in a domain I'd set it [**via GPO**](http://blogs.msdn.com/w32time/pages/group-policy-settings-explained.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The only solution that *actually* helped in my case (virtualized Windows Servers with no Active Directory) is described on this page:
http://www.pretentiousname.com/timesync/

It's actually about running an own Scheduled Task, making sure that the Time Service is started and then calling `w32tm.exe /resync`.

I exported the task to XML and then import it to every new installation.

It's insane. Btw, never had this problem for Active Directory members.